# How I use an array from another class?

Tags: java, class, arraylist

Hi I hope someone can help me. I want to access to an `Arraylist` from another `class`. For example in a java `class` named `array.java` is this array

```
array.class:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public static List<String> selledbooks(){
        List<String> booksdata = new ArrayList<String>();

        booksdata.add("booktitle1;ebook;19.99;2020;3");
        booksdata.add("booktitle2;ebook;4.99;2020;3");
        booksdata.add("booktitle3;audiobook;22.99;2016");
        booksdata.add("booktitle4;ebook;4.99;2020;streaming");
  
        return booksdata;
}

main.class:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> selledbooks = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        }

    private static void booksdata() {
        System.out.println(Daten.selledbooks());
        
    }
```

The array elements are categorized like this:

```
Book: title;booktype;price;edition 
ebook: title;booktype;price;edition;version 
audiobook: title;booktype;price;edition;mode
```

how can I access to the array from `array.class` in `main.class` and how can I sum up the `prices` for example of them?

Can I do this or do I need some Classes in `main.class` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define them as public, place them outside of any methods

```
public class myClass {

    public static int [] myArray = new int [10];   //defined outside of any method

    public static void main(String args []) {
       myClass2.setArray();
    }
}
```

```
public class myClass2 {

    public static void setArray() {
        myClass.myArray[0] = 1;
        myClass.myArray[1] = 20;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you give me an example with given information from me ..

Answer (score 0):

in array.class you can access the variables in main.class like this as long as you define them as public

main.booksdata

Comment: How can I define them you mean to import them ? I have a folder and in this folder are these two .class files so they both have the same package ...